# How to make a popup form AJAX in leaflet and execute function on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

What i'm basically trying to do,after clicking on each polygon a [popup form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7seO.jpg) appears  where the user will input some values,press submit and after the php script and function runs ,it will supposedly show some markers on the map.I'm trying to make this form work as AJAX and execute the function within.

I already ajax successfully a html form  before but it seems it needs some work to function properly within leaflet.

The form im trying to AJAX

```
var htmlformGuest = `

    <h2>Search for parking slots</h2>
    <form id="parkform" action="/findPark.php" method="post" >

        Enter the polygon id:<br>
    <input type="number" name="id_P" value="">
        <br>
        Max radius:<br>
    <input type="number" name="Radius" min="50" max="500" value="" placeholder="50">
        <br><b>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
        <input id="form-polygon-id" type="hidden" name="PolygonID">
        <input type="reset">
        </form>
`;
```

The function i want to include when submitting the form ( which im not sure it works since i need to first ajax the form!)

```
function putMultipleMarkers(jArrayId, jArrayLat, jArrayLng) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jArrayLat.length; i++) {
        var multipleMarker = new L.marker(jArrayLat[i], jArrayLng[i])
            .bindPopup(jArrayId[i])
            .addTo(geojson);
    }

}
```

What worked for me in a non-leaflet form previously was this code withing the function

```
$("#parkform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "findPark.php",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: alert('Marker Map'),
    })
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clean, but you can do `$('body').html(data)` on success:

```
$("#parkform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataForm = $(this).serialize();
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.post(
        url,
        dataForm,
        function(data) { // on success
            $('body').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Because the `data` is the code response of your request, then it's the same page with POST array values.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately,it does not work! It seems i need some kind of leaflet commands based on the doc. Not really sure.